# Connection refused Kubernetes

Tags: c#, kubernetes

I have frontend and backend running on kubernetes - say frontend and backend. Each of them can be individually accessed on localhost. But when I put these services in pods. Then the pods are unable to communicate with each other. I have exposed frontend as well as backend via Loadbalancer.

As in, I can access http://localhost:8081/ping and http://localhost:8083/doWork but http://localhost:8081/doMainWork that calls http://localhost:8083/doWork gives connection refused error. Without containers, if I only dockerize them then it works fine.

frontend.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        image: frontend:latest
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 5000
```

backend.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 8083
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: backend
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        image: backend:latest
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
```

HTTPClient in C#

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
      {
         BaseAddress = new Uri( "http://host.docker.internal:8083/" ),
         //BaseAddress = new Uri( "http://localhost:8083/" ),
         Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 )
      };
```

The error remains the same if I use localhost or host.docker.internal

Comment: Have you seen the hosts file of windows? it should be pointing to your private ip address but not the Loopback address (127.0.0.1)

Comment: @nalnpir private ip as in? C:\Poc\Backend>kubectl get service backend --watch
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
backend   LoadBalancer   10.99.134.140   localhost     8083:30843/TCP   5m59s

Comment: Since they're running in different pods, they won't be `localhost`; you need to contact the other Service's name.

Answer (score 0):

According to k8s documentation:

> A Service in Kubernetes is a REST object, similar to a Pod. Like all of the REST objects, you can  `POST`  a Service definition to the API server to create a new instance. The name of a Service object must be a valid  [DNS label name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names#dns-label-names).
>
> For example, suppose you have a set of Pods that each listen on TCP port 9376 and carry a label  `app=MyApp`:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: my-service
> spec:
>   selector:
>     app: MyApp
>   ports:
>     - protocol: TCP
>       port: 80
>       targetPort: 9376
> ```
>
> This specification creates a new Service object named "my-service", which targets TCP port 9376 on any Pod with the  `app=MyApp`  label.

Instead calling `localhost` you should call the `service` name.

Comment: I changed service definition to apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8083
      targetPort: 80
I tried using service name but I get host not found error.

Comment: Can you perform ping from one pod to another? Are all your pods in kube-system namespace running?